# Date picker select a specific range of date in Jquery UI / Jquery Easy UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I am currently using jquery easy ui date picker.  Here is the     [documentation](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#), with few option only, so it won't take you more than a minute to have a look.  it is good but i **need to select the date for a range start by tomorrow and within 30 days**

for example, if today is 16/4/2012, then the range should be **17/4/2012 to 16/5/2012** , i find quite difficult to start with as i do not know how to get the current date using jquery and set the range, disable the selectable item after i read that document.

Thank you.

Also, if the jquery easyui is not a good choice for this, any recommendation? i am using jquery ui as well. It is appreciate if answer  using either one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery UI you can use the `minDate` and `maxDate` syntax. `+1` and `+30` will be tomorrow and the date within 30 days, respectively.

Set the `options` accordingly.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: +1,
        maxDate: +30
    });
});​
```

You can check [a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8vQmq/).

Comment: How to set minDate and maxDate using Jquery Easy UI. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) has `minDate` and `maxDate` options you can set.

```
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Here's how you would set it up for your requirements:

```
$('#test').datepicker({
    minDate: '+1d', // Minimum date of 1 day from now (tomorrow)
    maxDate: '+30d' // Maximum date of 30 days from now (or '+1m' for 1 month)
});
```

This will only allow the days between `minDate` and `maxDate` to be selectable; all others will be disabled.